# Jquery Dynamically Inserted/Loaded Content Won't Fade In Smoothly

Tags: jquery, animation, fade, jquery-load

I have a piece of Jquery that first dynamically inserts a div -

```
var contact_popup = '<div id="contact-popup" style="display: none; z-index:200; width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>';
$('body').append(contact_popup);
```

And then pulls some content from another page and inserts it into the div -

```
$('#contact-popup').load("contact/index.html #contact-content");
```

And then fades that div in when you click a link on the page -

```
contact_item.click(function(){
    $('#contact-popup').fadeToggle(500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is that the popup doesn't fade in, it just appears after a slight delay. No matter how long you're on the page and you click the link, it still won't fade in.

What am I doing wrong?? Thank you!

Comment: What is `contact_item` in your `.click` event?

Comment: `event` is `undefined` here. use `contact_item.click(function(event){`

Comment: You need event delegation. Apply event on parent like '$('parent').on('click', contact_item, function(){});'

Comment: `contact_item` is the item in the menu to be clicked on that will trigger the popup. Trying event delegation, it seems to be acting in a similar way for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.

They key is *not* to perform the animation on *the wrapper you're loading the content into*, but **the wrapper that is *being* loaded from the external page**.

So I create a wrapper, style it and append it to the body:

```
var overlay_wrapper = '<div id="content-wrapper"></div>';
$('#content-wrapper').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    left: '0',
    top: '0',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%', 
    zIndex: '4'
});
$('body').append(overlay_wrapper);
```

Then, I load the content into this wrapper on click, and fade in the div being loaded from the other page in the .load method.

```
contact_item.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#content-wrapper').load("/tinite/contact/index.html #contact-content", function() { 
        $('#contact-content').hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
    history.pushState(null, null, 'contact');
});
```

(Thanks to Tamil Selvan for pointing out I need to define event). I also add 'contact' to the current URL with the `history.pushState`.

I'm not *entirely* sure why fading this other div works, but it makes the transition nice and smooth. Hope this might help someone else.

Edit - this only fades the content in it. To hide the content I'll put an if statement in that checks whether contact-content is visible or not and changes the function of the click depending on this.

Comment: Thanks mate, this has been of much help, even tho 6 years later :)